# How to set signature field in pagination & listing components of SXA?

Tags: configuration, sxa

I am trying to configure listing component for example Event list of SXA with pagination, but I am unable to understand the usage of signature field.

> List Signature - Signature is used to pair list with pagination component

What is this field used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use **Pagination** with **Page List** or any other **Paginable** rendering:

- EventList
- FileList
- PageList
- EventCalendar

simply parse selected rendering with **List Signature** rendering parameter

[image]

**SXA 1.1**

It seems right now Pagination rendering works with Page List only so you cannot use it with different renderings (I've got errors on my instance).

Comment: Yes you're right I also get errors while using pagination with EventList, FileList. It is only working with page list.